# Download list of directory/file names only from web server index

Tags: command-line, curl, wget, webserver, html

I'm trying to curl/wget a list of directories/files names available in a directory listing of a webserver.

For example from (randomly chosen) http://prodata.swmed.edu/download/, I'm trying to download:

```
bin
dev
etc
member
pub
usr
usr1
usr2
```

cUrl (`curl http://prodata.swmed.edu/download/`) gets me the whole HTML page, which I'd need to parse manually for all file/directory entries.

Is there a way to download the names of the available files/directories only, with curl/wget, without installing additional parser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP protocol has no feature to request a "list of files" from an HTTP server.

`curl` / `wget`/ browser requests a URL, which contains an arbitrary request string and the server sends back some arbitrary data.

However you can extract the names with following commands

```
curl --silent http://prodata.swmed.edu/download/ | grep -o 'href=".*">' | sed 's/href="//;s/\/">//'  

bin
dev
etc
member
pub
usr
usr1
usr2
```

Comment: `curl -s http://10.10.1.2/WEBDATA/ | grep -o 'href=".*">' | sed -e "s/href=\"//g" | sed -e 's/">//g'   ` this is what work for me

Answer (score 2):

`curl -s http://example.com/files/ | grep -o 'href=".*">' | sed -e "s/href=\"//g" | sed -e "s/\"\>//g"`

Gives me an experience like `ls` in a directory

Comment: `curl -s http://10.10.1.2/WEBDATA/ | grep -o 'href=".*">' | sed -e "s/href=\"//g" | sed -e 's/">//g'   ` this is what work for me